# Rails Data Modelling: How can I model a has_many relationship that's actually a collection of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-relation

To be more specific, I have a `User` model that **has_one** `Profile`, now I'm in the need to add a **has_many** relationship from `User` to a new model `Contact`, but `Contact` is really a collection of `Profile`s ("*User* **has_many** *Profile*s" behind the scenes).

[image: basic diagram]

How do I correctly model this? Is there a way to avoid creating the new Model `Contact` altogether?

My concern, and reason to ask this question is having to perform an inefficient query to retrieve the User Contacts *collection*: `user.contacts` and then for each `Contact` I'd have to create a Query to retrieve each `Profile`, right?

How I can make it so that when I do: `user.contacts` it retrieves a Collection of `Profiles` that **Doesn't** interfere/is independent of the `user.profile` relationship?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be necessarily need a new Model, but it's easiest (at least, in my opinion) to have one, just not in the way presented above.

Rails aside, you need a join table, like `user_profiles`, which contains foreign keys for `user_id` and `profile_id`.  Now, how you make that work is up to you.

Your `Contact` model here is actually, in a more Rails-y way, a `UserProfile` model.  So your User could look like:

```
class User
  has_many :user_profiles # the join table
  has_many :contacts, through: :user_profiles

  has_one: profile
end
```

Here, `user.contacts` would get you the profiles.  You still have that extra model, `UserProfile`, you just don't use it in practice:

```
class UserProfile
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Which you can build via:

`rails g model UserProfile user:references profile:references`

Hope that helps!

Comment: It does help a lot, thanks! a little follow up question, how would the Migration for UserProfiles Model would look like?

Comment: @jlstr I updated my answer to include the model and migration details

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much sir!